# set cookies safari ipad

Tags: ipad, gwt, safari

I can't get Safari on ipad to recognize the cookies I send.

It works on *OSX Safari*, on *iPad Chrome* but just not *iPad Safari*.

I have set **Accept Cookies** to **"Always"** in Safari's iPad settings to no avail.

I am using GWT and can see Web Inspector that the response header of contains Set-Cookie as usual with the value I expect(1).  It does not get set by Safari though.

If this were an iFrame issue, doesn't setting **Accept Cookies** to **"Always"** deal with that?
What can I do to work around this?

(1) `nick_name=me;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 11-Feb-13 02:32:22 GMT, xzy=25002, promoid=7b54c1ae-e76a-4f65-aebd-c8496132672a;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 11-Feb-13 02:32:22 GMT, rememberMe=25002:58322d58-b1b8-4f15-be68-11b610cf8c86;Path=/;Expires=Mon, 11-Feb-13 02:32:22 GMT`

Comment: You can eliminate whether this because of GWT via simple javascript sample. If it occurs even in javascript then tag your question in javascript as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to simply delete all cookies via Settings --> Safari --> Clear cookies and data

On next access the cookies then appeared.